# Variational autoencoder multiple outputs loss function with KL Divergence layer

Tags: keras, autoencoder

I need a help for writing loss function for the model below:

[image: My model]

There is 5 inputs and outputs. First 2 layers are categorical variables, variables 3 and 4 are binary variables and the 5th variable is continuous variable that I scaled from 0 to 1. From VAE I want to reconstruct them all. Could you help me with the code for loss function?

KL_divergence class looks like this one:

This layer is an identity layer that add the KL loss to the final loss.
Then your final loss can just be the one you were using above.
class KLDivergenceLayer(Layer):

```
""" Identity transform layer that adds KL divergence
to the final model loss.
"""

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.is_placeholder = True
    super(KLDivergenceLayer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def call(self, inputs):

    mu, log_var = inputs

    kl_batch = - .5 * K.sum(1 + log_var -
                            K.square(mu) -
                            K.exp(log_var), axis=-1)

    self.add_loss(K.mean(kl_batch), inputs=inputs)

    return inputs
```

and the loss function looks like this one:

```
def nll(y_true, y_pred):
    """ Negative log likelihood (Bernoulli). """
    #keras.losses.binary_crossentropy gives the mean
    #over the last axis. we require the sum
    return K.sum(K.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred), axis=-1)
```

With this code I dont't get correct reconstruction.